# Spring boot mongodb connection- credential issue with uri

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-rest

I am using the following to create a Spring-REST-Mongo project

Mongo 3.2.7 Spring 4.3.1 release Spring boot 1.3.6

I have created following user with the below privileges.

```
> use admin
switched to db admin
> db.getUser("UserAdminNew")
{
        "_id" : "admin.UserAdminNew",
        "user" : "UserAdminNew",
        "db" : "admin",
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "readWrite",
                        "db" : "admin"
                },
                {
                        "role" : "root",
                        "db" : "admin"
                },
                {
                        "role" : "readWrite",
                        "db" : "NEWTest"
                }
        ]
}
```

**Application.properties**

```
#spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://UserAdminNew:Dhara123@localhost:27017/NEWTest
```

As per spring boot documentation beyong Mongo 3.x we can connect thru the uri  to mongodb by providing the appropriate credentials.

**Application.java**

```
package main.java.springmongodbdatarest;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Product.java**

```
package main.java.springmongodbdatarest;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

public class Product {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String name;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String imageUrl;
    private double price;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }
    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }
    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }



}
```

**ProductRepository.java**

```
package main.java.springmongodbdatarest;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "products", path = "products")
public interface ProductRepository extends MongoRepository<Product, String> {

}
```

once i run my maven project & hit the url in my local i get the following response

**http://localhost:8080/**

```
{
  "_links" : {
    "products" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/products{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/alps"
    }
  }
```

}

**http://localhost:8080/products**

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Jul 26 11:12:02 IST 2016

There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).

{ "serverUsed" : "localhost:27017" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "not authorized on test to execute command { count: \"product\", query: {} }" , "code" : 13}
```

As you can see even if the db i have mentioned is NEWTest in the application.properties The error message clearly specifies unable to insert on default db "test"

I might be overlooking something because of which it is not taking the specified db n credentials.

Please suggest.Thanks In Advance.

**Error stack**

```
    2016-07-26 12:16:48.300 ERROR 8468 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Reque
rocessing failed; nested exception is com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { "serverUsed" : "localhost:27017" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "not authorized on test to execute command { count: \"produc
 query: {} }" , "code" : 13}] with root cause

com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { "serverUsed" : "localhost:27017" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "not authorized on test to execute command { count: \"product\", query: {} }" , "code" : 13}
        at com.mongodb.CommandResult.getException(CommandResult.java:76)
        at com.mongodb.CommandResult.throwOnError(CommandResult.java:131)
        at com.mongodb.DBCollection.getCount(DBCollection.java:1198)
        at com.mongodb.DBCollection.getCount(DBCollection.java:1153)
        at com.mongodb.DBCollection.getCount(DBCollection.java:1137)
        at com.mongodb.DBCollection.getCount(DBCollection.java:1106)
        at com.mongodb.DBCollection.count(DBCollection.java:1027)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.count(SimpleMongoRepository.java:146)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.findAll(SimpleMongoRepository.java:216)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:436)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:421)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:393)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:506)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy76.findAll(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.data.rest.core.invoke.PagingAndSortingRepositoryInvoker.invokeFindAll(PagingAndSortingRepositoryInvoker.java:66)
        at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.getCollectionResource(RepositoryEntityController.java:172)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Adding  When connected to mongo with out --auth everything works fine & can perform get post delete.

```
> use NEWTest
switched to db NEWTest
> show collections
Friends
product
users
usersD
> db.product.find().pretty();
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5797350f0206e6b7ef7a118a"),
        "_class" : "main.java.springmongodbdatarest.Product",
        "name" : "NEW GLASS",
        "title" : "Beatiful  Blue Glass ",
        "imageUrl" : "http://img.com",
        "price" : 5
}
>
```

Comment: did you try adding a property for db name

Answer (score 0):

You should use `spring.data.mongodb.username` and `spring.data.mongodb.password` in your application.

Full `application.properties` example : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

Comment: I have tried that already & did not work out.Noticed in the below link that it apparently works till Mongo 2.x where as i haveMongo 3.x
You can set spring.data.mongodb.uri property to change the URL and configure additional settings such as the replica set: but that also is taking the default test db

spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://user:secretpassword@mongo1.example.com:12345,mongo2.example.com:23456/test

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-nosql.html

Comment: Can you check mongo database connectivity with something else like a nodejs project ? (example : https://scotch.io/tutorials/an-introduction-to-mongodb#using-in-a-nodejs-application) or mongodb GUI admin tool like https://robomongo.org/

Comment: I can connect & perform post get delete if I  connect to monogo Db with out credentials.Only when my mongodb is running on --auth & i am trying to provide the credentials thru the properties file I am facing this issue.
Hence ,I think i must be a configuration issue on my part some how on providing the username & password.